# Ошибка Cl.exe при постройке проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Всем доброго вечера.
Собираю проект email [клиента] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/SMTP-Client-with-SSL-TLS).
Настроил include и lib директории, как указано в мануале. Компилирую в vs++2017, проект попросил Cl.exe. Нашел, добавил директорию с cl.exe в настройки проекта. Теперь при компиляции выдает ошибку - CL.exe завершилась с кодом -1073741515.
Что за ошибка и как все-таки скомпилировать проект?
Спасибо.

Comment: А это точно нужный cl?

Comment: Не знаю, подскажите как определить.

Comment: Нупросто запустите и посмотрите - это она? Код странный. Вот и думаю - может, она и вовсе не запускается?

Comment: Запускается, работает

Comment: Проверьте, установился ли с Visual Studio компилятор C++ - попробуйте создать стандартный Win32 или MFC проект в ней. Если их там нет, то вам нужно будет добавить поддержку C++ через инсталлятор. И не нужно будет указывать где находится компилятор или линкер, это все будет прописано в системных настройках IDE.

Comment: Все установилось, vc++ работает.

Comment: @j0hn Если VC++ работает, то студия не может искать CL.exe, потому как CL.exe это и есть компилятор. Студия с ним должна без всяких настроек работать.